# Php Stream to client while creating Tar file

Tags: php, download, filestream, tar, phar

I have a special request for my PHP application.

Basically, an user can request a backup of his data as a `TAR` file. This archive contains a `JSON` file with the database informations (Profile, Various data, etc.) and a directory with all the files the user has upload since his registration.

So far, I've made the following code:

```
$phar = new PharData($output_filename);

$table_dump = self::dump_tables($customers);

$manifest = array();
$manifest['generation_time']  = time();
$manifest['manifest_version'] = self::DUMP_VERSION;

$phar->addFromString(self::MANIFEST_FILE, json_encode($manifest) );
$phar->addFromString(self::DATA_FILE, json_encode($table_dump) );

sql::select(file::sql_table, sql::true, file::sql_key);
$files_list = sql::fetch_all();
if ($files_list) foreach($files_list as $file_guid) {
  $file_path = file::forge_file_path($file_guid);
  if(is_file($file_path))
    $phar->addFile($file_path, basename($file_path));
}

return $output_filename;
```

It successfully returns a valid path with a valid `TAR` file that i can download. Today, the download is automatically started through a `PHP Header` but it takes ages to pack the `TAR`.

What I would like to know is: **Is it possible to start downloading the file while it's being created ?** (As a `TAR` file is made of collapsed files.)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a guess: did you try using `php://output` as the filename?

Comment: Hello, Yes, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if PHP is writing the file you would need another thread to read from that file. PHP does not support multithreading. You could probably use exec() or an extension like [phtreads](http://pthreads.org/).

I did not used it myself yet. But I read an article about it and it seems this could solve your problem.

Good luck.